# how can check int field exist or not in firebase

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, flutter

[image]I have two button where if the field is exist then its shows one button otherwise its shows user other in which i will give  function to add data to my database ...i m using cloud firebase ...how can check the field is exist or not ...below is my code...

//if the score is not existing it will show a raised button so u can click on that to

//code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

BuildContext buildContext;
int filter = 0;
StreamSubscription<DocumentSnapshot> subscription;

class ScorePage extends StatelessWidget {

  final int score;
  ScorePage({Key key, @required this.score}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: new Text('Scroe Card'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
            child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0)),
                  new MaterialButton(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: new Text(
                      "Reset Quiz",
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Flexible(
                      child: StreamBuilder(
                        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('quiz score').snapshots(),
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                            return new Text("loading..");
                          } else {
                            return FirestoreListView1(
                              documents: snapshot.data.documents,
                            );
                          }
                        },
                      ))
                ])));
  }
}



class FirestoreListView1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents;
  FirestoreListView1({this.documents});
  @override
  FirestoreListView1State createState() {
    return new FirestoreListView1State();
  }
}

class FirestoreListView1State extends State<FirestoreListView1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context1) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.documents.length,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context1, int index) {
          int scoren = widget.documents[index].data['score1'];

          if () {
            return new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text("Submit Your Score",
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: "ChelaOne-Regular")),
              onPressed: (){
              },
            );
          } else {
            return new RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: new Text("no scores found"),
              onPressed: (){

              },
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method `containsKey` to check if your Document's data have that field.

```
    final bool hasScore = widget.documents[index].data.containsKey('Score1');

    if (hasScore) {
                return new RaisedButton(
                  child: new Text("Submit Your Score",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: "ChelaOne-Regular")),
                  onPressed: (){
                  },
                );
              } else {
                return new RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: new Text("no scores found"),
                  onPressed: (){

                  },
                );
              }
```

Don't forget to check if your `data` is not null first.

Comment: thanks its working ...now if I delete document field then its not showing anything button if I want to display another button if the whole field is empty only the collection is exist how can implement that

Comment: sorry I didn't catch your question, what do you need now?

Comment: sorry it my mistaken if delete whole document field it delete collection too

Comment: you can check using :   widget.documents == null ||  widget.documents.isEmpty

Comment: if i want show another button when the collection is not present how can I show that

Comment: what is the problem then?

Comment: now I want to display another button if the collection doesn't exist

Comment: use this :  widget.documents[index].exists() in order to check if the document exist, it the document does not exist then the collection neither.

Comment: or check the   widget.documents.length before the listview builder.

Comment: i used code :  if (! widget.documents[index].exists) {
            return new Text('welcome');  .....but its not working

Comment: datasnapshot.data.containsKey("name") seems to be deprecated... `error: The method 'containsKey' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.`